# How to remove digits and special characters from the beginning of a string?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

For instance I have

```
'234 - ? Hi there'
```

The result should be:

```
'Hi there'
```

Comment: Look into Oracle's regexp_replace function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For oracle you have the `regexp_replace` function. So you could do the below to replace non-alphabetic characters from the beginning of the string:

```
select regexp_replace('24 Hi','^([^a-zA-Z]*)','') from dual
```

The first `^` in `^([^a-zA-Z]*)` is to match the beginning of the string. The second `^` is to match any non-alphabetic characters.

Comment: While this is helpful, the question is tagged as Oracle. Oracle provides the regexp_replace function so there's no need to write a custom function in T-SQL, which wouldn't run on Oracle anyways.

Comment: @GauthamM this doesn't work in oracle. could you please provide the oracle version if you can? thanks

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle you can use `REGEXP_REPLACE()`. I recommend using a slightly different regex than the one in the accepted answer; there's no reason to do any replacing on a pattern that can be of zero width. Additionally, the parentheses are unnecessary since you don't need to capture a group:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(my_column, '^[^A-Za-z]+') FROM my_table;
```

We can also exclude the 3rd argument to `REGEXP_REPLACE` since in Oracle, a NULL and an empty string are equivalent. Another alternative in Oracle is to use the POSIX character class `[:alpha:]`:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(my_column, '^[^[:alpha:]]+')
  FROM my_table;
```

[Please see the SQL Fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8fa416/7). You can [read more about POSIX character classes here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html).

Answer (score -2):

Use this Function to remove numeric and Special symbols.

```
CREATE function [dbo].[RemoveNumericandSpecialSymbolValue](@str varchar(500))  
returns varchar(500)  
begin  
declare @text int  
set @text=0  
while 1=1  
begin  
set @text= patindex('%[^a-z .]%',@str)  
if @text <> 0  
begin  
set @str = replace(@str,substring(@str,@text,1),'')  
end  
else break;  
end  
return @str  
end
```

Example:

```
select dbo.RemoveNumericandSpecialSymbolValue('234 - ? Hi there')
```

Comment: While this is helpful, the question is tagged as Oracle. Oracle provides the regexp_replace function so there's no need to write a custom function in T-SQL, which wouldn't run on Oracle anyways.